# Check if a full text catalog exists in 2000

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to detect whether a database has a specific full text catalog so that I can either use it or avoid executing part of a script that would create errors without the catalog.  I know in sql server 2005 you can use:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs WHERE name = 'catalog_name')
```

But we have to support sql server 2000 still and I can't use that.  Is there another way to check for the catalog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The @@version check might need altering, but this should work:

```
declare @catalogExists tinyint
set @catalogExists = 0

if (@@version like ('%SQL%Server%2000%')) begin
    if exists(SELECT 1 FROM [master].[dbo].[sysfulltextcatalogs] WHERE name = 'catalog_name') 
        set @catalogExists = 1
end
else begin
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs WHERE name = 'catalog_name')
        set @catalogExists = 1
end

print @catalogExists
```

Comment: On a server where I know we have the catalog I'm looking for my `[master].[dbo].[sysfulltextcatalogs]` table is blank.  Is that even possible?

Comment: Silly me, I didn't realize each DB has a sysfulltextcatalogs table to check.  I was looking at the wrong DB when trying this out.